# How do I find what computer modem I have in Linux Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: linux

I can not find my modem in Ubuntu Linux 11.10. It is not detected in my laptop, how do I find what my modem is?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it turns up with lshw and lspci? Have you looked up what your laptop model usually comes with on the website of the OEM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from the modem you use (no support for Ubuntu 11.10), because as i know that most modem support it with windows GUI interface as evidenced by the number of modems that can be run in windows
because when i use Ubuntu 11.10, only detects the modem device's type only